# Matter js: How to remove objects from a stack?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

***Matter.js***....
Hi: I'm trying to remove some objects contained in a stack from the screen.
My code creates the objects, does everything it's supposed to, but I need to remove 'electrons' from the screen. After hours of research, study and guessing, I haven't been able to do it. I've spent most of my time trying to apply 'Composite.remove'.
Thank you for any help that you can provide...

relevant parts of my code:

```
const leftEngine   = Engine.create()

const leftWorld   = leftEngine.world

const leftRender = Render.create({
  element: document.querySelector('#left'),
  engine: leftEngine,
  options:{
        wireframes: false,
        width: w*0.1,
        height: h*0.6,
        background: '#000'
    }
})

const createelectron1 = function(x, y) {
    return Bodies.circle(Math.random()*w*0.1, Math.random()*h, 2, {
    restitution: 1,
    friction: 0,
    frictionAir: 0,
    render: {
        fillStyle: "red",
        visible: true
      }
  });
}

const createatom1 = function(x, y) {
    return Bodies.circle(Math.random()*w*0.1, Math.random()*h, 5, {
    isStatic: true,
    restitution: 1,
    render: {
        fillStyle: "white",
        visible: true
    }
    });
  }

makeleftelectrons();
makeleftatoms();

function makeleftelectrons(){
    const initialShapes = Composites.stack(w*0.1, 0, electrondens, 20, 2, 4, function(x, y){
    return createelectron1(x, y)
})

}
function makeleftatoms(){
const initialShapes2 = Composites.stack(w*0.1, 0, 10, 10, 2, 4,  function(x, y){
  return createatom1(x, y)
})

const initialShapes = Composites.stack(w*0.1, 0, electrondens, 20, 2, 4, function(x, y){
  return createelectron1(x, y)
})

const initialShapes2 = Composites.stack(w*0.1, 0, 10, 10, 2, 4,  function(x, y){
  return createatom1(x, y)
})

const currentLeft = [
  initialShapes,
  initialShapes2,
  leftground,
  leftceiling
]

currentLeft.forEach(body =>{
  World.add(leftWorld, body)
})

Matter.Runner.run(leftEngine)

Render.run(leftRender)
const leftRunner = Matter.Runner.create()
Matter.Runner.run(leftRunner, leftEngine)

//additional code:

function removeCircle(removenum) {
    Composite.remove(initialShapes, bodies[removenum].id); 
}

atomdensityslider.oninput = function() {
    electrondens = Number(atomdensityslider.value).valueOf();
    for (let removenum= 0; removenum < 1000; removenum++) {
        removeCircle(removenum);
    }    
}
```

Comment: You want to remove the whole stack or you want to remove some objects from the stack and leave others?

Comment: I want to remove some from the stack and leave others... and thank you for responding!

Comment: Thanks. Which ones? I don't see any application attempts involving `Composite.remove()` here. Can you share that code?

Comment: Hi ggorlen... I apologize for my late reply, and thank you so much for your help: At the bottom of the above code I have added my attempt at removing objects from a stack under the heading 'additional code'. To initialize the removal of objects, I repurposed an HTML rangeslider. Move the slider and the objects are supposed to be removed.

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to show that code?

Comment: I've added the additional code to the above...

Comment: All right, thanks, but what about `bodies`? Where was that defined?

Comment: Hmmm... Body and Bodies are good, but my bodies... I can't see it defined anywhere, yet it works wonderfully in creating hundreds of objects, and I can step through them. I think that I should study whatever's happening before I continue in my efforts. You've seriously been a great help in pointing this out (and I'm feeling a little silly). Thank you.